# is there a functor that derefences a (smart) pointer, upcasts it, and then calls a method on it?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, functional-programming

I have

```
class A: public B { ...}

vector<A*> v;
```

I want to do

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), mem_fun_deref(B::blah()));
```

(Actually I have:

```
vector<unique_ptr<A>>
```

but it shouldn't matter)

I need to upcast and call the member function.

Comment: I don't mind using boost, but actually it's more complicated -- I need to upcast and then call the member function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::lambda` can do it

```
vector<A*> v; ...
using boost::lambda::_1;
using boost::lambda::bind;
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), bind(&B::blah, *_1));
```

No need to upcast. A member pointer to a base-class member can be applied to a derived class too.

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
```